# How can I create a recursive type based on object structure?

Tags: typescript

I have a recursive object structure defined as such:

```
interface Item {
  name: string;
  type: 'string' | 'url' | 'list' | 'file',
  require?: boolean;
  allowedFileTypes: string[];
  subFields: Item[];
}

const items = {
  name: "navigation",
  type: "list",
  subFields: [
    {
      name: "label",
      type: "string",
      defaultValue: "",
      require: true,
    },
    {
      name: "url",
      type: "url",
      defaultValue: "",
      require: true,
    },
    {
      name: "images",
      type: "list",
      subFields: [
        {
          name: "label",
          type: "string",
          defaultValue: "",
          require: true,
        },
        {
          name: "icon",
          type: "file",
          allowedFileTypes: ["png", "svg"],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

I'm attempting to derive the following from this structure:

```
// The output would be:
type Items = {
  navigation: Array<{
    label: string;
    url: string;
    images: Array<{
      label: string;
      icon: 'png' | 'svg';
    }>
  }>
}
```

In a separate question, someone managed to help me use typeof to derive a flat version of this structure but I got stumped on the recursive part with TS. [Here's the solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmADgVyhGBeGBtAUDGAb3wJjAEMBbAUwC4YAicsMEZMYamsNBgGhIEoAT0R1GAGzjR+gmBGQAjAGJxqEgCYR6eUqWJ69FGvQahEw2YdIixp6ACcEAcyvWYG6gDNyyCVAA1cglkcQY3PQBfAWsDd2MwxVQocAAZckV1CMNbMMcXbL1PHz9A4NDTQphouQI46wTTJKgUsABVBwkqoVEw5E7uj29ffyCQsKqavQBdGOqBaZhydFBIKFxcXJgAQRY2Di5qHnQsOOwAaXgwGFyQLyuUNGwABmnsBgUVNU0IBjewZCUTION4MBJ-ab0fJgZy4SK4AD0CJuvR2e3YnG4aEwRERyL05mEUKgThhAG48YZmq10pkJMTSc4KUiqclwB16fISS5mcjIkA).

Basically, how can I use typeof to recursively derive my nested type based on a defined object as a generic object? Something flexible enough to also defined the required (as optional values) and for icon the png/svg options as a single string.

Is this perhaps more than TS can handle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing we need to do here is to use `as const` again to preserve the type information of `items`. Also `items` should be a tuple and not an object to make the following logic easier.

```
const items = [{
  name: "navigation",
  type: "list",
  subFields: [
    {
      name: "label",
      type: "string",
      defaultValue: "",
      require: true,
    },
    {
      name: "url",
      type: "url",
      defaultValue: "",
      require: true,
    },
    {
      name: "images",
      type: "list",
      subFields: [
        {
          name: "label",
          type: "string",
          defaultValue: "",
          require: true,
        },
        {
          name: "icon",
          type: "file",
          allowedFileTypes: ["png", "svg"],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}] as const
```

A possible solution for this problem would then look like this:

```
type ExpandRecursively<T> = T extends object
  ? T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: ExpandRecursively<O[K]> } : never
  : T;


type GenerateItems<T extends readonly any[]> = {
  [K in keyof T & `${bigint}` as T[K] extends { name: infer N extends string } 
    ? N 
    : never
  ]: 
    T[K] extends { subFields: infer S extends readonly any[] } 
      ? GenerateItems<S>[]
      : T[K] extends { type: infer Type extends string } 
        ? Type extends "string"
          ? string 
          : Type extends "url"
            ? string
            : Type extends "file"
              ? T[K] extends { allowedFileTypes: infer FT extends readonly string[] }
                ? FT[number]
                : never
              : never
        : never
}
```

This solution requires a lot of manual checking of the `type` field. We have to manually check the field for each possible value and act accordingly.

```
type Items = ExpandRecursively<GenerateItems<typeof items>>

// type Items = {
//     navigation: {
//         label: string;
//         url: string;
//         images: {
//             label: string;
//             icon: "png" | "svg";
//         }[];
//     }[];
// }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=82&ssc=5&pln=46&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChnIhwYQBcyAzmFKAOYDc%20yYAngA5nIDkVNItXZAB9uAVygAbQSK4TgVadxjAJELgBomUCAEdRwbQH5yAIwD2Z1XBCMCcCRLMB3CABMAYiogAVdhArkvHQA2gC6tpSiJp4QEq4BaJhhjAC%20uLgIZiBUyMCYFMgAvMjBeAREJOQAREQAbsC0cGDAWVWaBKwc1XJUbUwUUTFxCcFMBGUEkxWcVRJwJrF9k5OdM0H8S8vIrhDwohJgAGr2ojOby9p6BpzUp%202TKffjY1PEM%20IS5yt%201R9fBDs9gdjhJTtV-shLvptORbhAnshHi8JstptVgBg4LR-BDVt15GAIQNosBYvFyKMtpMUVTCG9uvNFgiqXjkFV1rQIctAXB9kcTmdmVsoddYVA7i9lkjaThJVs0WzgJkQFzvl02cpVKq7A5nG5PKpfBwRlU2Bt1GyKLVOaEhQRpVtbS8HU6UqFkHACsqqOlcKtkABRAAebGsrgAShAEOIKMBarEWAAebwAPiKyG8yAgQcgIHiyDMJgAVlGwExDBmszmIHmCqAYNBkAB5ZAV7AlADSuRAyAA1hAWGYYM3QuRg6G85Ho1BY-GJEmm8EO6E0ylkOQQBB41AmORvIx0v6AOI16BNCDoCAYCjJqu5-PaOCuLLzj0gFhhNPFCZL7t9gdDpWABkyAAAYACTYCYDSgGAKSgR6BTeEu7rZveBTtgq9aNgAcneNb5hyiLIC8FZ4S8G5btATCjiRyzIcu%20G1jgkQkmSCTYVAyAAMpMQ%20EBPi%20LBvh%207prnKFYnpuUDnpe16JtxKZhHKe4oXxGHMD83YNlxRooGhBEFER4kyhWenqZa1B0FUcrLBWRG2ZMe5%20BZVR-I5dmUFZ-AeU5GYuQZzFVJqEA2TKVJmWpgX5u29iOC4HheHpHEgDpyDuJm0UFI%20z4gK%20HJhIivkRelyEgKIGALFAoTFVslHbrVBD1dRMrNTuaR%20i5ckFMU45hlOMZxgmiZSWekDdYmqyAXkV4UCmKbpAA9ItmkcIks3pngy3ynA9SNM0WTkFtK0ynMCwSIE3kMLg20yh8l18Ndt20hiWL%20EdN0neFBBnbED10Iwz3fUqh1smanLCJa1pVIDX1UikySfVsCPhEjKRAA)

Comment: Oh wow, I think I was missing const this entire time and it was throwing me off! Your solution is a lot tighter, I'm going to experiment with it and get back to you. Thank you so much @Tobias S. you're extremely helpful and I'm learning so much from your support rn.